# How to write a derived class which specifies type parameters for a templated base

Tags: c#, c++, templates, generics, polymorphism

I'm learning C++ and I am having trouble bringing this design pattern over from C#. I can't work out if this pattern will not work in C++ or if I just have the incorrect syntax.

In the example I want to create a class that decodes a bitset.

In C# with generics it would look something like this :

```
abstract class Base<T>
{
  public abstract T GetValue(BitArray bits);
}

class Derived : Base<MyType>
{
  public override MyType GetValue(BitArray bits)
  {
    // Do some magic to decode this bitset
  }
}
```

This is my naive attempt in C++

```
template<T,Q> 
class Base
{
public:
    Base() = default;
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
    virtual T* GetValue(const std::bitset<Q>& bits) const = 0;
}

class Derived : Base<MyType, 32>
{
public:
    Derived();
    ~Derived();
    MyType* GetValue(const std::bitset<32>& bits) const;
}

MyType* Derived::GetValue(const std::bitset<32>)
{
    // Do some magic to decode this bitset
}
```

The compiler throws all manner of errors when I try to compile that C++ code (which I imagine is wrong in a number of ways).

How might I achieve this pattern of having the inheriting class specify a type parameter for the template of the base in C++?

Comment: You forgot semicolons after your class declarations.

Comment: Is `MyType` a class, or is it supposed to be a template parameter for `Derived`?

Comment: `a class that decodes a bitset` - what does that mean? You should show us your `MyType`. Also, for this particular case, there is no point to have virtual base class, as it looks like this method should be static

Comment: Also you most likely want to use public inheritance, not private (as by default).
Try changing `class Derived : Base` to `class Derived : public Base`

Answer (score 1):

> The compiler throws all manner of errors when I try to compile that C++ code (which I imagine is wrong in a number of ways).

- missing semicolon after class declaration
- wrong syntax in template declaration
- missing includes for std::bitset
- `MyType` is not defined
- you shouldn't use public or protected inheritance from `Base`

More over, it's no clear why would you have that method virtual at all. You should also perhaps return by value from `Derived::GetValue`, or perhaps a smart pointer to `MyType`:

```
unique_ptr<MyType> Derived::GetValue(const std::bitset<32> &) {...}
```

[Sample code](https://ideone.com/QBuQJp):

```
#include <bitset>
#include <memory>

class MyType;

template<typename T, unsigned Q>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<T> GetValue(const std::bitset<Q>& bits) const = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base<MyType, 32>
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<MyType> GetValue(const std::bitset<32>& bits) const;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors:

```
template<T,Q>                       // Wrong
template<typename T, std::size_t Q> // Fixed

MyType* Derived::GetValue(const std::bitset<32>)         // Wrong
MyType* Derived::GetValue(const std::bitset<32> &) const // Fixed
```

You also need a semicolon following a class declaration, so the `}` character that follows each class declaration needs to be `};`.

After making those changes (and forward-declaring `MyType`, which I assume already is declared in your code), the code compiles.

Answer (score 0):

No offense, but your errors are just due to a couple of more or less obvious mistakes:

- no `;` after class declaration
- missing definition of `MyType`
- missing `#incldue <bitset>`
- mismatch between declaration and definition of `GetValue`
- missing `typename` for `T`
- `Q` should be a `size_t`

Fixing those [it compiles](http://ideone.com/i5iCTr):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset> //
using namespace std;

struct MyType{}; //

template<typename T,size_t Q>  //
class Base
{
public:
    Base() = default;
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
    virtual T* GetValue(const std::bitset<Q>& bits) const = 0;
}; //

class Derived : Base<MyType, 32>
{
public:
    Derived();
    ~Derived();
    MyType* GetValue(const std::bitset<32>& bits) const;
}; //

MyType* Derived::GetValue(const std::bitset<32>&) const //
{
    // Do some magic to decode this bitset
}


int main() {
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```